# Given a string of HTML code, how do I go through every tag and remove all "event" attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, string

Using JQuery, I want to go through every single tag.

**If that tag has an attribute that starts with "on", then remove that attribute completely.**

I know how to loop through all tags:

```
newvalue = $('<div>' + value + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
}).html();
```

But, how do I loop through all the attributes and match the string with "on"?

Answer (score 1):

you wont be able to see all the On prefix since it is not an actuall attribute on the html markup but referencing through event handler.

but you can see all the events NAMe which a re binded to this elements.

you should use :  ( in the each function)

```
$(this).data('events');
```

example :

```
$.each($("#Myel").data("events"), function(i, e) {
    alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I'm not sure if you're working on strings or on actual dom-nodes. Suppose it's strings, something like:

```
var
  value = '<div onclick=""><span onfocus="" class=""><img onload="" /></span><a onclick=""></a></div>',
  newvalue;

newvalue = $('<div>' + value + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each([].slice.call(this.attributes, 0), function (idx, attr) {
    if (attr.nodeName.substr(0, 2).toLowerCase() === 'on') {
      $(self).removeAttr(attr.nodeName);
    }
  });
}).end().html();

console.log(newvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newvalue = $('<div>' + value + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
  // current element
  var thiz = $(this);
  // attributes of element
  var atts = thiz.get(0).attributes;
  for (var i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
    var attrName = atts[i].name.trim();
    // ignore attribute which does not start with "on"
    if (attrName.toLowerCase().indexOf("on") != 0)
      continue;
    // remove
    thiz.removeAttr(attrName);
  }
}).html();
```

EDIT: Use DOM functions

```
newvalue = $('<div>' + value + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
  // attributes of element
  var atts = this.attributes;
  for (var i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
    var attrName = atts[i].name.trim();
    // ignore attribute which does not start with "on"
    if (attrName.toLowerCase().indexOf("on") != 0)
      continue;
    // remove
    this.removeAttribute(attrName);
  }
}).html();
```

Comment: `var thiz = $(this); var atts = thiz.get(0).attributes;` is a bit redundant, as you first make a jQuery object and then *break out of it* again using `get(0)`. `var atts = this.attributes;` is the same.

Comment: Thank @Yoshi, my practice is to make a `thiz` jQuery object variable at the first line inside loop, after that write code to interact with defined `thiz`. Just a habit, and it's not good for this question.